# How to delete a record permanently from Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

Models:-
I have a staff model

```
class Staffs(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    admin = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    address = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    objects = models.Manager()
```

Then I have a subject model

```
class Subjects(models.Model):
    id =models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    subject_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    course_id = models.ForeignKey(Courses, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1) #need to give defauult course
    staff_id = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    #created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    #updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    objects = models.Manager()
```

Views:-

```
def add_subject(request):
    courses = Courses.objects.all()
    staffs = CustomUser.objects.filter(user_type='2')
    context = {
        "courses": courses,
        "staffs": staffs
    }
    return render(request, 'hod_template/add_subject_template.html', context)



def add_subject_save(request):
    if request.method != "POST":
        messages.error(request, "Method Not Allowed!")
        return redirect('add_subject')
    else:
        subject_name = request.POST.get('subject')

        course_id = request.POST.get('course')
        course = Courses.objects.get(id=course_id)
        
        staff_id = request.POST.get('staff')
        staff = CustomUser.objects.get(id=staff_id)

        try:
            subject = Subjects(subject_name=subject_name, course_id=course, staff_id=staff)
            subject.save()
            messages.success(request, "Subject Added Successfully!")
            return redirect('add_subject')
        except:
            messages.error(request, "Failed to Add Subject!")
            return redirect('add_subject')


def manage_subject(request):
    subjects = Subjects.objects.all()
    context = {
        "subjects": subjects
    }
    return render(request, 'hod_template/manage_subject_template.html', context)


def edit_subject(request, subject_id):
    subject = Subjects.objects.get(id=subject_id)
    courses = Courses.objects.all()
    staffs = CustomUser.objects.filter(user_type='2')
    context = {
        "subject": subject,
        "courses": courses,
        "staffs": staffs,
        "id": subject_id
    }
    return render(request, 'hod_template/edit_subject_template.html', context)


def edit_subject_save(request):
    if request.method != "POST":
        HttpResponse("Invalid Method.")
    else:
        subject_id = request.POST.get('subject_id')
        subject_name = request.POST.get('subject')
        course_id = request.POST.get('course')
        staff_id = request.POST.get('staff')

        try:
            subject = Subjects.objects.get(id=subject_id)
            subject.subject_name = subject_name

            course = Courses.objects.get(id=course_id)
            subject.course_id = course

            staff = CustomUser.objects.get(id=staff_id)
            subject.staff_id = staff
            
            subject.save()

            messages.success(request, "Subject Updated Successfully.")
            # return redirect('/edit_subject/'+subject_id)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("edit_subject", kwargs={"subject_id":subject_id}))

        except:
            messages.error(request, "Failed to Update Subject.")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("edit_subject", kwargs={"subject_id":subject_id}))
            # return redirect('/edit_subject/'+subject_id)



def delete_subject(request, subject_id):
    subject = Subjects.objects.get(id=subject_id)
    try:
        subject.delete()
        messages.success(request, "Subject Deleted Successfully.")
        return redirect('manage_subject')
    except:
        messages.error(request, "Failed to Delete Subject.")
        return redirect('manage_subject')
```

Now when I want to add a subject, it goes by like this

Subject Name:-
Python

(let me choose from a list of courses I have entered like MCA,BCA etc.)
Course:-
MBA

( lets me choose from a list of staff names I have entered like Pavan Kumar, Naveen Patil, etc.)
Staff:-

ivor aaa

alan decker

Fulton strong

Pavan Kumar

Naveen Patil

The main issue I m facing is I have already deleted staff values like Ivor aaa, alan decker, and Fulton strong, but it's still displaying in the list of values. How do I get rid of these values?

I have tried
Staffs.objects.all.delete() but still values like Ivor aaa, alan decker and fulton strong in the list

Comment: Staffs.objects.all().delete()

Comment: Can you show the relevant template?

Comment: Your `staff_id` is a FK to `CustomUser` model. It's gonna list your users, not instances from your `Staffs` model.